# How can you put 20 turtles on a circle in Python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have to put 20 turtles on verticles of a polygon with 20 sides, so they will be on a circle with regular spacing.

I have class Turtle, where I want to put those 20 turtles. I know how to put more turtles in one file, but how can I situate them in a circle?

```
# Already working
class Turtle:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.heading = 0
        self.lines = []

    def left(self, angle):
        self.heading -= angle

    def right(self, angle):
        self.heading += angle

    def forward(self, d):
        nx = self.x + d * math.cos(self.heading * math.pi / 180)
        ny = self.y + d * math.sin(self.heading * math.pi / 180)
        self.lines.append((self.x, self.y, nx, ny))
        self.x, self.y = nx, ny

    def save(filename, lines):
        f = open(filename, "w")
        f.write('<svg viewBox="-500 -500 1000 1000">')
        s = '<line x1="{}" y1="{}" x2="{}" y2="{}" style="{}" />'
        for i in lines:
            for x1, y1, x2, y2 in i:
                f.write(s.format(x1, y1, x2, y2, "stroke:black;stroke-width:1"))
        f.write("</svg>")
        f.close()

    # Here is just a try to put more turtles with more lines in one file
    # But I can't do this with 20 turtles...
    def set_turtles():
        global all_lines
        turtle_names = []
        t_red = Turtle(-100, 0)
        turtle_names.append(t_red)
        t1 = Turtle(0, 100)
        turtle_names.append(t1)
        t2 = Turtle(0, -100)
        turtle_names.append(t2)
        for turtle in turtle_names:
            for i in range(4):
                turtle.forward(10)
                turtle.left(90)
            all_lines.append(turtle.lines)
        save("drawing_one.html", all_lines)
        f.close()
```

Comment: Don't delete your questions when they've accrued answers. That's not how the site works.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than do everything with a custom turtle class, let's use Python's turtle class to help solve the problem.  We'll still need our own custom turtle class (not called `Turtle`) that can record lines it generates when `foward()` is called.  Plus implement a static method to dump all lines drawn by all custom turtles to an SVG file.  But all other methods we can simply inherit!

With this approach, to record lines, we don't need trigonometry, but instead record a turtle's position before we call `super().forward(...)` and record the turtle's postion afterward.

Finally, we don't need to keep track of our custom turtles, but instead use `Screen().turtles()` and filter out those that aren't instances of our custom class.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

RADIUS = 100

class SVG_Turtle(Turtle):
    TEMPLATE = '<line x1="{}" y1="{}" x2="{}" y2="{}" style="{}" />'
    STYLE = 'stroke:black;stroke-width:1'
    HEADER = '<svg viewBox="-500 -500 1000 1000">'
    FOOTER = '</svg>'

    def __init__(self, position):
        super().__init__(visible=False)
        self.lines = []

        self.penup()
        self.goto(position)

    def forward(self, distance):
        position = self.position()
        super().forward(distance)
        self.lines.append((position, self.position()))

    @staticmethod
    def save(filename):
        with open(filename, 'w') as file:
            file.write(SVG_Turtle.HEADER)

            for turtle in screen.turtles():
                if not isinstance(turtle, SVG_Turtle):
                    continue

                for ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) in turtle.lines:
                    file.write(SVG_Turtle.TEMPLATE.format(x1, y1, x2, y2, SVG_Turtle.STYLE))

            file.write(SVG_Turtle.FOOTER)

screen = Screen()
yertle = Turtle(visible=False)  # standard Python turtle to lay down our custom ones
yertle.penup()
yertle.sety(-RADIUS)

screen.tracer(False)

for _ in range(20):
    turtle = SVG_Turtle(yertle.position())
    turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(0, 0))  # Optional visual detail I added
    yertle.circle(RADIUS, 360 / 20, 20)

for turtle in screen.turtles():
    if isinstance(turtle, SVG_Turtle):
        for _ in range(4):
            turtle.forward(10)
            turtle.left(90)

screen.tracer(True)

SVG_Turtle.save("drawing.html")
```

[image]

Even if you aren't allowed to use Python's turtle to help solve your own turtle problem, this should hopefully give you some ideas how to proceed and how to organize your code.